# Highlight TODO permanently in vim(nvim)/treesitter

Tags: neovim, treesitter, lunarvim

I'm trying to highlight `TODO` comment while using `treesitter`.
I have already read [github issue of treesitter](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter/issues/236) and installed `TSInstall comment`.

and running `:hi link @text.note Todo` temporarily works but when I exit the vim page and reopen it, it seems like the highlighting groups has been reset. How can I apply this command every time I open my file using `vim`?

I'm currently using lunar vim's default setting color scheme.

edit) Fri.Dec 2.2022
This is my whole config file

```
--[[
lvim is the global options object

Linters should be
filled in as strings with either
a global executable or a path to
an executable
]]
-- THESE ARE EXAMPLE CONFIGS FEEL FREE TO CHANGE TO WHATEVER YOU WANT

-- general
lvim.log.level = "warn"
lvim.format_on_save.enabled = false
lvim.colorscheme = "habamax"
-- to disable icons and use a minimalist setup, uncomment the following
-- lvim.use_icons = false

-- keymappings [view all the defaults by pressing <leader>Lk]
lvim.leader = "space"
-- add your own keymapping
lvim.keys.normal_mode["<C-s>"] = ":w<cr>"
-- lvim.keys.normal_mode["<S-l>"] = ":BufferLineCycleNext<CR>"
-- lvim.keys.normal_mode["<S-h>"] = ":BufferLineCyclePrev<CR>"
-- unmap a default keymapping
-- vim.keymap.del("n", "<C-Up>")
-- override a default keymapping
-- lvim.keys.normal_mode["<C-q>"] = ":q<cr>" -- or vim.keymap.set("n", "<C-q>", ":q<cr>" )

-- Change Telescope navigation to use j and k for navigation and n and p for history in both input and normal mode.
-- we use protected-mode (pcall) just in case the plugin wasn't loaded yet.
-- local _, actions = pcall(require, "telescope.actions")
-- lvim.builtin.telescope.defaults.mappings = {
--   -- for input mode
--   i = {
--     ["<C-j>"] = actions.move_selection_next,
--     ["<C-k>"] = actions.move_selection_previous,
--     ["<C-n>"] = actions.cycle_history_next,
--     ["<C-p>"] = actions.cycle_history_prev,
--   },
--   -- for normal mode
--   n = {
--     ["<C-j>"] = actions.move_selection_next,
--     ["<C-k>"] = actions.move_selection_previous,
--   },
-- }

-- Change theme settings
-- lvim.builtin.theme.options.dim_inactive = true
-- lvim.builtin.theme.options.style = "storm"

-- Use which-key to add extra bindings with the leader-key prefix
-- lvim.builtin.which_key.mappings["P"] = { "<cmd>Telescope projects<CR>", "Projects" }
-- lvim.builtin.which_key.mappings["t"] = {
--   name = "+Trouble",
--   r = { "<cmd>Trouble lsp_references<cr>", "References" },
--   f = { "<cmd>Trouble lsp_definitions<cr>", "Definitions" },
--   d = { "<cmd>Trouble document_diagnostics<cr>", "Diagnostics" },
--   q = { "<cmd>Trouble quickfix<cr>", "QuickFix" },
--   l = { "<cmd>Trouble loclist<cr>", "LocationList" },
--   w = { "<cmd>Trouble workspace_diagnostics<cr>", "Workspace Diagnostics" },
-- }

-- TODO: User Config for predefined plugins
-- After changing plugin config exit and reopen LunarVim, Run :PackerInstall :PackerCompile
lvim.builtin.alpha.active = true
lvim.builtin.alpha.mode = "dashboard"
lvim.builtin.terminal.active = true
lvim.builtin.nvimtree.setup.view.side = "left"
lvim.builtin.nvimtree.setup.renderer.icons.show.git = false

-- if you don't want all the parsers change this to a table of the ones you want
lvim.builtin.treesitter.ensure_installed = {
  "bash",
  "c",
  "javascript",
  "json",
  "lua",
  "python",
  "typescript",
  "tsx",
  "css",
  "rust",
  "java",
  "yaml",
}

lvim.builtin.treesitter.ignore_install = { "haskell" }
lvim.builtin.treesitter.highlight.enable = true

-- generic LSP settings

-- -- make sure server will always be installed even if the server is in skipped_servers list
-- lvim.lsp.installer.setup.ensure_installed = {
--     "sumneko_lua",
--     "jsonls",
-- }
-- -- change UI setting of `LspInstallInfo`
-- -- see <https://github.com/williamboman/nvim-lsp-installer#default-configuration>
-- lvim.lsp.installer.setup.ui.check_outdated_servers_on_open = false
-- lvim.lsp.installer.setup.ui.border = "rounded"
-- lvim.lsp.installer.setup.ui.keymaps = {
--     uninstall_server = "d",
--     toggle_server_expand = "o",
-- }

-- ---@usage disable automatic installation of servers
-- lvim.lsp.installer.setup.automatic_installation = false

-- ---configure a server manually. !!Requires `:LvimCacheReset` to take effect!!
-- ---see the full default list `:lua print(vim.inspect(lvim.lsp.automatic_configuration.skipped_servers))`
-- vim.list_extend(lvim.lsp.automatic_configuration.skipped_servers, { "pyright" })
-- local opts = {} -- check the lspconfig documentation for a list of all possible options
-- require("lvim.lsp.manager").setup("pyright", opts)

-- ---remove a server from the skipped list, e.g. eslint, or emmet_ls. !!Requires `:LvimCacheReset` to take effect!!
-- ---`:LvimInfo` lists which server(s) are skipped for the current filetype
-- lvim.lsp.automatic_configuration.skipped_servers = vim.tbl_filter(function(server)
--   return server ~= "emmet_ls"
-- end, lvim.lsp.automatic_configuration.skipped_servers)

-- -- you can set a custom on_attach function that will be used for all the language servers
-- -- See <https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig#keybindings-and-completion>
-- lvim.lsp.on_attach_callback = function(client, bufnr)
--   local function buf_set_option(...)
--     vim.api.nvim_buf_set_option(bufnr, ...)
--   end
--   --Enable completion triggered by <c-x><c-o>
--   buf_set_option("omnifunc", "v:lua.vim.lsp.omnifunc")
-- end

-- -- set a formatter, this will override the language server formatting capabilities (if it exists)
-- local formatters = require "lvim.lsp.null-ls.formatters"
-- formatters.setup {
--   { command = "black", filetypes = { "python" } },
--   { command = "isort", filetypes = { "python" } },
--   {
--     -- each formatter accepts a list of options identical to https://github.com/jose-elias-alvarez/null-ls.nvim/blob/main/doc/BUILTINS.md#Configuration
--     command = "prettier",
--     ---@usage arguments to pass to the formatter
--     -- these cannot contain whitespaces, options such as `--line-width 80` become either `{'--line-width', '80'}` or `{'--line-width=80'}`
--     extra_args = { "--print-with", "100" },
--     ---@usage specify which filetypes to enable. By default a providers will attach to all the filetypes it supports.
--     filetypes = { "typescript", "typescriptreact" },
--   },
-- }

-- -- set additional linters
-- local linters = require "lvim.lsp.null-ls.linters"
-- linters.setup {
--   { command = "flake8", filetypes = { "python" } },
--   {
--     -- each linter accepts a list of options identical to https://github.com/jose-elias-alvarez/null-ls.nvim/blob/main/doc/BUILTINS.md#Configuration
--     command = "shellcheck",
--     ---@usage arguments to pass to the formatter
--     -- these cannot contain whitespaces, options such as `--line-width 80` become either `{'--line-width', '80'}` or `{'--line-width=80'}`
--     extra_args = { "--severity", "warning" },
--   },
--   {
--     command = "codespell",
--     ---@usage specify which filetypes to enable. By default a providers will attach to all the filetypes it supports.
--     filetypes = { "javascript", "python" },
--   },
-- }

-- Additional Plugins
-- lvim.plugins = {
--     {
--       "folke/trouble.nvim",
--       cmd = "TroubleToggle",
--     },
-- }

-- Autocommands (https://neovim.io/doc/user/autocmd.html)
-- vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("BufEnter", {
--   pattern = { "*.json", "*.jsonc" },
--   -- enable wrap mode for json files only
--   command = "setlocal wrap",
-- })
-- vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("FileType", {
--   pattern = "zsh",
--   callback = function()
--     -- let treesitter use bash highlight for zsh files as well
--     require("nvim-treesitter.highlight").attach(0, "bash")
--   end,
-- })
--

vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, '@text.note', { link = 'Todo' })
vim.api.nvim_command("redraw")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add permanently this link for highlight group, you can use Neovim API [`nvim_set_hl`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html) function.

Add in your Neovim configuration :

```lua
vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, '@text.note', { link = 'Todo' })
```

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work :(, I attached my whole config file on the question. Most of them are just comments though

Comment: I found out that It really depends on the color scheme I set. I applied your solution and changed then my color scheme it worked! thanks